# CUPS web interface problem

Tags: printing, interface, cups-lpd

I'd like to know how we can get information about the work of every printer (like the name of the user,  how much pages were printed, and the date of every work printed) from the web interface of cups ! the completed jobs from the web interface doesn't show the name of the user ?!!

Comment: Take a look under the "Jobs" tab, there should be an option to show "Completed Jobs"

Comment: yes, but I need the name of the user the completed jobs " show the name as Unknown

Comment: This is data from `/var/log/cups/page_log`.